# How do I get Android Styleguide Switches in Appcelerator?

Tags: appcelerator, android-styles

The on/off switches shown on http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/switches.html#switches are awesome. I can't figure out how to get them in Appcelerator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a titanium thing, it is android. If you want to support 2.x, you cant have the 4.x look. You would have to change the manifest to change the SDK level support. Here is a good article that helped me. http://developer.appcelerator.com/doc/mobile/android-custom-androidmanifest